# Zeebus Puzzle #5

Tags: word, rebus

Going *back in time* for this one. Us old folks should get it pretty easily ;)

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it

> Be Kind, Rewind? Isn't that the old Blockbuster slogan?

*Edit: I remember the answer and I'd like to think I'm not **that** old!*

Comment: Doh, I feel stupid for not seeing that!

Comment: To play is human, to rewind is divine! @El-Guest, I don't _feel_ that old either ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thoughts

> You have a backwards bed with kin in between it. Maybe a broken bed?