# Revrebuseserse!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rebus

Inspired by [this rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70939/zeebus-puzzle-5) and [this Riley puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66920/riley-riddles-in-reverse?noredirect=1&lq=1), I went out to look for some more rebuses online (backward ones, at least)... and that's when I found the following rebus puzzle. This is not mine, but I will credit the source once I have ticked the answer.

> > **Rebuses in Reverse**
>
> We've all seen a rebus like "midstuckdle" (stuck in the middle). The following clues are "revrebuseserse" (rebuses in reverse). That is, the clues below are answers to rebuses which all use the "in" construction.
>
> However, the original rebus from the clues below will actually form a word. For example, "Not old in actually existing" would be "renewal" (new in real). Can you solve the rest?
>
> 1. A female relative in quickly departed the scene
> 2. Not off in a length of time
> 3. Fluid for writing in a part of a plane
> 4. A light at night in wet dirt
> 5. To talk in a soft, loving voice in a confidence trick
> 6. To separate in a legal document

If you've seen this puzzle before, lucky you!

---

**Edit:**

Here is the source.

> [You better not look at the answers and then post an answer here pretending it is your own effort.](https://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/17621/rebuses-in-reverse.html)

Comment: Yeah, I saw after the fact, sorry.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know hahah, no worries. I'm not *that* smart :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hmm...

A female relative in quickly departed the scene

> AUNT in FLED -> FLAUNTED

Not off in a length of time

> ON in HOUR -> HONOUR

Fluid for writing in a part of a plane

> INK in WING -> WINKING

A light at night in wet dirt

> STAR in MUD -> MUSTARD

To talk in a soft, loving voice in a confidence trick

> COO in CON -> COCOON

To separate in a legal document

> PART in DEED -> DEPARTED

Comment: Yup; yup; yup! Good job! :D **Edit:** All of 'em are correct! Well done!

Comment: Wow this was pretty fast

Comment: The first three were straightforward, the last three took a bit of thinking but weren't too bad!

Comment: Sometimes, I wonder if you're part of the NSA El-Guest, because you solve these so quickly...

Comment: @Joe-You-Know the tinfoil hats that I wear help me focus my brainpower, that's all ;P

Comment: @Joe-You-Know hahah, glad I'm not the only one who thought that...

Comment: Usually I wait a little while before I give a tick, but you answered this so quickly, what am I waiting for? Congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt at this,

A light at night in wet dirt

> Mustard

Comment: Yup, that is correct! Nice work! :D